# Create a time series NDVI chart for multiple locations in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am trying to create a time-series NDVI chart for multiple locations using MODIS NDVI 16 day composites. Each location is a geometry.point + buffer zone.
I combined the locations into a feature collection and applied "seriesByRegion" to how NDVI has been changed at each location over time, but the error message popped up as below. What is wrong with my code?

```
// Create a 1km radius buffer zone around each location 
var a008 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-75.66296798,   39.77349598).buffer({'distance': 1000}), {label: 'a008'});  
var a012 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-75.71956502,   39.757637).buffer({'distance': 1000}), {label: 'a012'})
var a017 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-75.52674403,   39.79960699).buffer({'distance': 1000}), {label: 'a017'})
var a046 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-75.85959201,   39.68713899).buffer({'distance': 1000}), {label: 'a046'})
var a059 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-74.93536003,   39.88139098).buffer({'distance': 1000}), {label: 'a059'})


// Add the five features to the map
Map.addLayer(a008, {}, 'a008');
Map.addLayer(a012, {}, 'a012');
Map.addLayer(a017, {}, 'a017');
Map.addLayer(a046, {}, 'a046');
Map.addLayer(a059, {}, 'a059');


// Combine the five areas into a feature collection
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection([a008, a012, a017, a046, a059]);
print(roi, 'roi');


// Import the MODIS data and filter it  
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
            .filterBounds(roi)  // filter by roi
            .filterDate('2006-01-01', '2010-12-31');  // filter by date
print(modis, 'modis');


// Select the NDVI band
var modisNDVI = modis.select('NDVI');
print(modisNDVI, 'modisNDVI');


// The documentation states that we need to apply a scaling factor of 0.0001 for the NDVI-band to be displayed correctly 
// To do so, we will need to write a short function
var scale_factor = function(image) {
  return image.expression('float(b("NDVI")*0.0001)')  // create a function to apply the scale factor, 0.0001 to a single image
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end'])  // add the time index property for the scaled image
};


// Apply a map function to apply the scale factor to each Image in our ImageCollection
var modisNDVI_scaled = modisNDVI.map(scale_factor);

   
// Create a customized chart for changes in NDVI over time at multple locations
var roi_modis_medianNDVI = 
          ui.Chart.image
          .seriesByRegion({
            imageCollection: modisNDVI_scaled,
            regions: roi,
            reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),   
            seriesProperty: 'label',
            scale: 250})    // MODIS resolution 250 m
          .setOptions({
            title: 'MODISTerra_16day composites: Median NDVI for 5 cases',
            vAxis: {title: 'Median NDVI',
                  viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 1}
                  },
            hAsix: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MM', gridlines: {counts: 12}},
                  });
print(roi_modis_medianNDVI);
```

[image]